# EF6 Migrations with Npgsql get DbProviderServices error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-migrations, npgsql

I'm trying to test the Entity Framework 6 migrations with Npgsql 2.0.14.3 to complete the support of my opensource PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator library that allow to use EF Migrations with Postgresql.

The test class I'm writing is this ([click here for github page](https://github.com/darionato/PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator/blob/e0fc36b2bb0fbe82cbc3d16c851abd77f903807c/EntityFramework.PostgreSql/EntityFramework.PostgreSql.Test/IntegrationTests/PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGeneretorHistoryTest.cs)):

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql;
using Npgsql;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace EntityFramework.PostgreSql.Test.IntegrationTests
{

    [TestFixture]
    public class PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGeneretorHistoryTest
    {

        private const string ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=testEF6;User Id=postgres;Password=p0o9i8u7y6;CommandTimeout=20;Preload Reader = true;";
        private const string ProviderName = "Npgsql";


        [Test]
        public void GenerateInsertHistoryOperation()
        {


            var migrator = new DbMigrator(new LocalMigrationConfiguration());

            migrator.Update();


        }

        public class LocalMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<LocalPgContext>
        {
            public LocalMigrationConfiguration()
            {
                AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
                SetSqlGenerator("Npgsql", new PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
                MigrationsNamespace = "EntityFramework.PostgreSql.Test.IntegrationTests.Migrations";
                MigrationsAssembly = typeof (LocalPgContext).Assembly;
                TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(ConnectionString, ProviderName);
            }
        }

        public class LocalPgContext : DbContext//, IDbProviderFactoryResolver, IDbConnectionFactory
        {/*
            public DbProviderFactory ResolveProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
            {
                return DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Npgsql");
            }

            public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
            {
                return new NpgsqlConnection(nameOrConnectionString);
            }*/
        }
        /*
        public class LocalConfiguration : DbConfiguration
        {
            public LocalConfiguration()
            {

                // can't set this cos NpgsqlServices is internal
                SetProviderServices(
                    "Npgsql", provider: NpgsqlServices.Instance
                    );
            }

        }
        */
    }
}
```

The test method `GenerateInsertHistoryOperation` doesn't get initialize becouse it return this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:
The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql, Version=2.0.14.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'.
Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider.
This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6 or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

I added an App.confing file to set the provider ([github link](https://github.com/darionato/PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator/blob/e0fc36b2bb0fbe82cbc3d16c851abd77f903807c/EntityFramework.PostgreSql/EntityFramework.PostgreSql.Test/App.config)):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

At this point, I don't know if Npgsql 2.0.14.3 isn't still supporting EF6 or if I'm missing something on my code.

[Click here to see it on github](https://github.com/darionato/PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would love seeing the completed project as PostgreSQL migrations would be very useful in my latest project which is unfortunately using EF 6.

I think the npgsql version you need is the latest beta version, try to use this line in the package manager to install the EF 6 version of npgsql

```
Install-Package Npgsql.EF6 -Pre
```

Comment: It works! Now I'm finding others problems but I hope to get well working release in little time.

Comment: Great! Happy to hear i could help you with that.